# How do I replace repetitive elements in an array matching another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
array_main = [23432, 3434, 312, 32432] 
array_second = [23432, 312]
```

I want to replace the elements in `array_main` with `0` matching the elements of `array_second`, so the output should look like:

```
array_main = [0, 3434, 0, 32432]
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array_main.map { |e| array_second.include?( e ) ? 0 : e }
```

And if you drop that requirement about replacing with 0, you can simply write

```
array_main - array_second
```

Comment: i am not sure if the questioner wanted to replace it in place ( in the array_main), but if so, then (s)he should use the destructive method `map!`, instead of `map`

Comment: @Zippie: Since which verion of Ruby is `map!` available, that I managed to miss it?

Comment: @Zippie: That `map!` is a funny name anyway, who has ever heard of mappings destroying their domain? It's real fun to try `e = array_main.map!` and then manually call `e.next` several times, and see how `array_main` is destroyed. Is this useful, or what?

Comment: Why is `map!` funny? It's an in-place mutation of the original array, which is useful if you don't want to create a new variable. It's potentially faster too, because no extra variable allocation should be happening. And, it's been [part of Ruby for a long time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Array.html#method-i-map-21).

Comment: @theTinMan: No, no, I don't mean that `map!` itself is funny, it is an amazing piece of functionality, that I regret is not available also for `Hash`. Just the name is funny, map with bang!!! Modifies the functional domain!!! That sounds like a math joke, it makes me laugh. Functional programming flowing in reverse!!! `a = 1, 2, 3; e = a.map!; e.each { 42 }`. (I'm drunk again.)